# Twitter share links

Tags: twitter

I would like to add a button to my website to give the opportunity to my visitors to share content to twitter and I use the following code :

```
<a href=
    "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=TwitterStories&text=Check%20out%20this%20app%20" 
    class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-url="http://test.com">Tweet #TwitterStories</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

The problem is that the url's address is visible. I would like to add a link and display only a phrase (e.g "check this link") which will link to my website.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. No it is not. Have you seen any tweets on Twitter which look like that?

Comment: No I have not. I just wonder if there is a way.